# Что и почему выведет код на Python? Оператор is

Tags: python, python-3.x, операторы

Что и почему выведет код на Python?

```
x = 1
y = 1
y = pow(10, 30, 10**30-1) # => 1
print(x, y, x is y) # => ???
```

Понимаю чем отличается `is` от `==`, но все равно не могу понять причину, почему код выводит `False`. Думаю, что как-то связано с самим `pow`, но объяснить причину, почему `y` больше не ссылается на тот-же элемент в памяти, что и `x` не могу.

Comment: id(y) до pow и после распечатайте, и тогда поймёте

Comment: Это ясно, id у них разные становятся. Мне важно понять, почему. Если я допустим сделаю y += 1 и следом y -= 1, то id не изменится. Если я сделаю pow(2, 2, 2**2-1), то тоже.

Comment: `pow` в примере из комментария id не меняет. Потому что id всех маленьких целых чисел фиксированы. В диапазоне от -5 до 256 питон кеширует целые.

Comment: Вы обнаружили ошибку в `pow`. Она не всегда выдаёт маленькие числа из кеша. Хотя должна. Браво!

Comment: Всем кто меня слышит! Плюсуйте эту великолепную находку!

Comment: Это ошибка, её будут чинить: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91117

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Так уже починили в 3.10, насколько я понял из той ссылки. В 3.11 сейчас проверил у себя - уже починено.

Answer (score 2):

интересный факт: Разница заключается в том, что is проверяет идентичность (объектов),его используют, чтобы удостовериться, что переменные указывают на один и тот же объект в памяти, а == проверяет равенство (значения).

Answer (score 2):

Да, это ошибка в интерпретаторе `cpython`, потому что вообще-то питон всегда кэширует небольшие числа и они должны совпадать и по `is` тоже. Но в данном случае нашёлся небольшой глюк:

> `x_divrem` always returns fresh ints, never cached small ints. This behavior is relied upon in the `long_true_divide` function, as it mutates the returned quotient

То есть глюк этот находится в функции, которая берёт остаток от деления. Изменения по этому багу были внесены в код для версии питона 3.10, там этой проблемы уже не должно быть. Я пробовал на версии 3.11, там ваш код уже точно выдаёт `True`.